# Firestore: Version history of documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I'm looking for a proper way to structure Firestore database to handle multiple version histories of documents inside a single collection.

For example: I have a collection named **offers** which have multiple **documents** which correspond to multiple offers. For each of these documents, I'd like to have **history** of changes, something like changes on Google Docs.

Since documents support only adding fields directly or nesting another collection, here's a structure I had in mind:

```
collections: offers
 - documents: offer1, (offer2, offer3, ...)
     - fields populated with latest version of the offer content
     - nested collection named history
         - nested documents for each version (v1, v2, v3), which in turn have fields specifing state of each field in that version.
```

This seems a bit overly complicated since I have latest state and than nested collection for history. Can this be somehow in flat structure where latest item in array is the latest state, or something similar.

Also, history state is generated on a button click, so I don't need every possible change saved in a history, just snapshots when user saves it.

I'd like to use Firebase as my DB for this, as I need it some other things, so I'm not looking into different solutions for now.

Thanks!

EDIT: According to the Alex's answer, here's my another take on this.

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- offers (collection)
        |
        --- offerID (document)
        |   (with fields populated )
        |        |
        |        --- history (collection) //last edited timestamp
        |            |
        |            --- historyId
        |            --- historyId
        |
         --- offerID (document)
            (with fields populated with latest changes)
                 |
                 --- history (collection) //last edited timestamp
                     |
                     --- historyId
                     --- historyId
```

This way I can query whole `offers` collection and get array of offers together with latest status since it's on the same level as the collection itself. Then if I need specific content from history state, I can query history collection of specific offer and get it's history states. Does this make sense?

I'm not sure about denormalization as this seems like it solves my problem and avoids complication.

Once more, requirements are: 
- being able to fetch all offers with latest state (works) 
- being able to load specific history state (works)

Just every time I update history collection with new state, I overwrite the fields directly in offerID collection with the same, latest, state.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you transfer the data to history collection when there's an update to the offer? I have the same problem as yours. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, your above schema might work but you'll need to do some extra database calls, since Firestore queries are shallow. This means that Firestore queries can **only** get items from the collection that the query is run against. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections. So there is no way in which you can get one document and the corresponding history versions that are hosted beneath a collection of that document in a single query.

A possible database structure that I can think of, would be to use a single collection like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- offerId (collection)
        |
        --- offerHistoryId (document)
        |        |
        |        --- //Offer details
        |
        --- offerHistoryId (document)
                 |
                 --- //Offer details
```

If you want to diplay all history versions of an offer, a single query is required. So you just need to attach a listener on `offerId` collection and get all offer objects (documents) in a single go.

However, if you only want to get the last version of an offer, then you should add under each offer object a `timestamp` property and query the database according to it descending. At the end just make a `limit(1)` call and that's it!

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> I need to get a list of all offers with their latest data

In this case you need to create a new collection named `offers` which will hold all the latest versions of your offers. Your new collection should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- offers (collection)
        |
        --- offerHistoryId (document)
        |        |
        |        --- date: //last edited timestamp
        |        |
        |        --- //Offer details
        |
        --- offerHistoryId (document)
                 |
                 --- date: //last edited timestamp
                 |
                 --- //Offer details
```

This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. If you are new to NoQSL databases, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding. It is for Firebase realtime database but same rules apply to Cloud Firestore.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

In your particular case, when you want to create an offer you need to add it in two places, once in your `offerId` collection and once in your `offers` collection. Once a new history version of an offer is created, there is only one more operation that you need to do. As before, add the `offerHistoryId` document in your `offerId` collection, add **the same** object in your `offers` collection, but in this case you need to remove the older version of the offer from the `offers` collection.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I actually didn't know that you can't get deeply nested objects. Just tried and you're right. However, this structure also doesn't resolve all problems. For example, I need to get a list of all offers with their latest data, and here I don't see the way to do it since each offer is in it's own collection. I'm curious if you have a way about that. I can share my idea afterwards :)

Comment: Nice insight on denormalization. Sound crazy, but I get the idea where it's coming from. Still, I think my use case is not for it and I've attached another approach to structuring this. Can you take a look again? Thanks.

Comment: It is almost the same as the first one. IMHO, if I were you, I'll use denormalization. It's sounds a little weird but it's quite easy. You're welcome Sebastijan, cheers!

Comment: I'll look a bit more into it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: This post is very old, but for anyone who doesn’t know that as of 2020 firestore supports something called ‘collectionGroup queries’ which means you can query across multiple collections with the same name within your project’s firestore database, you can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) this answers your question in the comment I hope!  @SebastijanDumančić

Comment: Hey @HasinthaAbeykoon thanks for the update. I don't think it solves any issues described in the original question, since it just avoid multiple firestore calls for a functionality that already kinda existed. But it's a cool timesaver nonetheless. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I can think of it like this. Each **offers** document will have **offerHistoryID** as number.

- You can have a separate root collection for versioned documents of offers(say **offers_transactions**).
- Now write an update trigger cloud function on **offers** document which will have both after and before values of the document.
- Before doing the doc update, you can write the **before** values into the **offers_transactions** along with timestamp and latest historyID.
- Increment the offerHistoryID by 1 for that offer and update the doc with new values.

Now you can query the root collection **offers_transactions** for historic transactions based on your filters. This way you can keep your root collection offers cleaner.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your thoughts! I've already implemented the latest version that I've written in my question. I've decided to skip the normalization and use nested approach with history subcollection for each offer document where root offer document holds the latest state of the offer. Your idea is ok, but I'd skip incrementing since you have timestamp which can be used for ordering purposes. Also, you're right about update triggers, I should have offloaded some of the logic there. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution my team uses to leverage Google Cloud Functions to add every collection update to a dedicated "history" collection in Firestore (no command line necessary):

1. Identify path of document to watch: **COLLECTION-NAME/{documentID}** (or define a specific document to watch)
2. Create a new [Cloud Function](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/) (1st gen because 2nd gen doesn't support Firestore triggers yet)
3. Set trigger as any Firestore "[write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore.documentbuilder.html#onwrite)" event watching the document path from **Step 1**.
4. In the Cloud Function's inline code editor, select the language of your choice (I'll use Python), and include `google-cloud-firestore==2.6.0` in your requriements.txt file (or whatever the [latest version](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest) is)
5. Finally, define your Cloud Function's code (be sure to import Firestore correctly!)

   ```
    def hello_firestore(event, context):
        resource_string = context.resource
        # print out the resource string that triggered the function
        print(f"Function triggered by change to: {resource_string}.")

        # now print out the entire event object
        print(str(event))

        # now import firestore and add event to the 'history' collection
        from google.cloud import firestore
        db = firestore.Client(project="YOUR-PROJECT-ID")
        newHistDoc = db.collection(u'history').add(event)
   ```