# Firebase Firestore Documents changes history (like Activity log/ History for changes in each Doc)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make an Activity log system or history for my docs, so every time a field is modified in a document i want to record or save that so i can see after changes history made on each document.

how i can achieve that ? i don't want to save the full doc on each change and then have tons of duplicated docs, if possible i just want to get the changed field (ex. name: 'john' -> name: 'jack').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i don't want to save the full doc on each change and then have tons of duplicated docs

Once a document has changed it becomes a new document. So you won't have duplicate documents unless you make changes that were previously made. Please also note that in Cloud Firestore there are no field-level permissions or access to a document. It's the entire document, or nothing. So if you want to change a field within a document for example from:

```
userName = "John"
```

into

```
userName = "Jack"
```

You'll will get the entire document and **not** only the `userName` property that has been changed.

Cloud Firestore listeners fire on the document level. There is no way to get triggered with just particular fields in a document.

If you want to get notified only of specific fields, consider adding an extra collection with documents that only contain those fields. This sort of data duplication is quite common in NoSQL solutions such as Firestore and for that, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding. It is for Firebase real-time database but same principles apply to Cloud Firestore.

For a database schema you can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53442460/firestore-version-history-of-documents/53445752)**.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve something like this is to store the `before` and `after` changes happening to the doc, in a new document, which you can add in a subcollection. The changes are available with cloud functions `onUpdate` trigger. I have written in depth about this topic on my blog, have a look.

https://blog.emad.in/audit-logs-for-firestore-documents/

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this by creating a cloud function that triggers on all document updates in all collections:

```sh
--trigger-resource=projects/$PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/{collection_id}/{document_id}
```

In the cloud function you can obtain all the updated fields and their values through the data object.

Python example:

```py
def main(data, context):
    # Extract resource
    resource = context.resource
    resource_split = resource.split('/')
    collection_name = resource_split[-2]
    document_id = resource_split[-1]

    # Get old fields
    data_old_values = data['oldValue']
    data_old_values_fields = data_old_values['fields']

    # Get updated fields
    data_updated_mask = data['updateMask']
    data_updated_fields = data_updated_mask['fieldPaths']

    # Get new field values
    data_new_values = data['value']
    data_new_values_fields = data_new_values['fields']

    # `data_updated_fields` is a list of the fields that has been changed
    # `data_old_values_fields` is a dictionary with the old values of the document
    # `data_new_values_fields` is a dictionary with the new values of the document
```