# Firestore Database Transaction Monitoring

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, stackdriver

I need some inputs regarding Firestore Monitoring. I have found three ways to monitor the firestore transactions. First one is to go to Usage Tab in Firestore console. Second one is through Quotas in App Engine Tab(GCP Console). Third one is through creating dashboards in Stack Driver monitoring. But i am able to get the same information from First and third option like read/write operations. What i want is transaction level monitoring like which user has created/updated/deleted the document. So for that level of monitoring what can i do in Firestore? I have created the dashboard but not able to get this user level transaction information. Please help.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for an audit log. Please, see more detail there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461435/does-cloud-firestore-have-an-audit-trail